# C++ console crashes after running

Tags: c++

guys, i have a problem.
After i run the program, the console just crashes.
`terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  basic_string::replace: __pos (which is 4294967295) > this->size() (which is 9)`

I mean, you will see.In the program there is an option "Add person", and when i add one, its all okay.But when i enter the program to add second person it crashes.Please, help!

The source code of the programs is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

system("chcp 1251 > nul");
system("title PeopleData");

string firstName;
string midName;
string lastName;
string fullName;
string line;
long ID = 27560000;
int age;
char gender;

cout << "1.Add person" << endl;
cout << "2.Read file" << endl;
cout << "3.Exit" << endl << endl;
cout << "Please, enter your choice: ";
int choice;
cin >> choice;

if(choice == 1)
{
    system("cls");

    ofstream myfile("Data.txt", ios::app);

    ifstream file("Data.txt");
    string IDLine;
    int numberOfLines = 0;
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while (getline (file, line) )
        {
            numberOfLines ++;
        }
        file.close();
        ifstream file("Data.txt");
        int y = 0;
        line = "";
        while(getline(file, line))
        {
            IDLine = line;
            if(y == numberOfLines - 5)
            {
                goto NextStep;
            }
            y++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Unable to open file";
    }

    NextStep:
    string LastID = IDLine;
    if(LastID != "")
    {
        LastID.replace(LastID.find("ID: "), string("ID: ").length(), "");
        ID = atoi(LastID.c_str()) + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        ID = 27560000;
    }
    cout << "First Name: ";
    cin >> firstName;
    cout << endl << endl;

    cout << "Middle Name: ";
    cin >> midName;
    cout << endl << endl;

    cout << "Last Name: ";
    cin >> lastName;
    cout << endl << endl;

    cout << "Age: ";
    cin >> age;
    cout << endl << endl;

    cout << "Gender (m / f): ";
    cin >> gender;

    fullName = firstName +  " " + midName + " " + lastName;

    myfile << "First Name: " << firstName << "\n";
    myfile << "Middle Name: " << midName << "\n";
    myfile << "Last Name: " << lastName << "\n";
    myfile << "Full Name: " << fullName << "\n";
    myfile << "Age: " << age << "\n";
    myfile << "Gender: " << gender << "\n";
    myfile << "ID: " << ID << "\n";
    myfile << "\n---------------\n\n";
    myfile.close();
    file.close();
    return 0;
}

if(choice == 2)
{
    system("cls");
    ifstream myfile ("Data.txt");
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while ( getline (myfile,line) )
        {
            cout << line << '\n';
        }
        myfile.close();
    }
    else
    {
        setcolor(12);
        cout << "Unable to open file";
    }
}
if(choice == 3)
{
    return 0;
}

system("pause > nul");
return 0;
```

}
`

Comment: It says you called `replace` with an invalid string index. I wonder why that might possibly be - maybe `find` returned `string::npos` because it didn't find the string in the string?

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: Yes, i know.
But its weird, because yesterday it worked, and im just confused now.

Comment: And also just run the program to see.
It works, but after i enter the program to enter another person then it crashes.

Comment: It's not the "console" that crashes. It's your program.